# Selecting all max values of column for each distinct value of other column

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to get a list of most used tags for posts on a website on a given day. I currently have this query:

```
SELECT posts.pdate, tags.tag, count(posts.pid) as post_count
FROM posts, tags
WHERE posts.pid = tags.pid
GROUP BY posts.pdate, tags.tag
ORDER BY posts.pdate;
```

This provides me with each distinct tag, along with the date they are used on as well as how many posts used them, returning me with this:

```
2020-09-10|CMPUT291|1
2020-09-10|computing|1
2020-09-10|database|2
2020-09-10|frequentTag1|2
2020-09-10|relational|2
2020-09-10|sql|1
2020-09-10|tieTag1|2
2020-09-11|Database|1
2020-09-11|data|1
2020-09-11|relational|1
2020-09-11|sql|1
2020-09-13|Database|1
2020-09-13|Sql language|1
2020-09-13|access|1
2020-09-13|frequentTag3|2
2020-09-13|query|3
2020-09-13|relational|3
2020-09-13|sql|1
2020-09-17|Database|1
2020-09-17|frequentTag3|3
2020-09-17|query|1
2020-09-17|relational|1
2020-09-17|sql|1
2020-09-17|sql language|1
2020-09-20|RELATIONAL|1
2020-09-20|database|1
2020-09-20|query|1
2020-09-20|sql language|1
2020-09-25|database|1
2020-09-25|sql language|1
2020-09-30|boring|2
2020-09-30|extra tag|1
2020-09-30|fun|3
2020-09-30|just here|1
2020-09-30|more tag|1
2020-09-30|sleep|3
2020-09-30|tag tag|1
2020-09-30|tag test|1
2020-09-30|test tag|1
```

But, I now need to make it only give me the rows that have the max (or all of them with max in case of a tie) for each date.
I WANT to be able to use MAX(count(posts.pid)) but I know that doesn't work so I need to find an alternative.
I should get a final result of this:

```
2020-09-10|database|2
2020-09-10|frequentTag1|2
2020-09-10|relational|2
2020-09-10|tieTag1|2
2020-09-11|Database|1
2020-09-11|data|1
2020-09-11|relational|1
2020-09-11|sql|1
2020-09-13|query|3
2020-09-13|relational|3
2020-09-17|frequentTag3|3
2020-09-20|RELATIONAL|1
2020-09-20|database|1
2020-09-20|query|1
2020-09-20|sql language|1
2020-09-25|database|1
2020-09-25|sql language|1
2020-09-30|fun|3
2020-09-30|sleep|3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

APPLICABLE SCHEMA:

```
create table posts (
  pid       char(4),
  pdate     date,
  title     text,
  body      text,
  poster    char(4),
  primary key (pid),
  foreign key (poster) references users
);

create table tags (
  pid       char(4),
  tag       text,
  primary key (pid,tag),
  foreign key (pid) references posts
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT pdate, tag, post_count
FROM (
  SELECT p.pdate, 
         t.tag, 
         COUNT(*) post_count,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.pdate ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM posts p INNER JOIN tags t
  ON p.pid = t.pid
  GROUP BY p.pdate, t.tag
)
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY pdate, tag;
```

You should use a proper `JOIN` with an `ON` clause instead of that outdated syntax with the WHERE clause.